# SOAP UI - Multiple tests transmissions

Tags: web-services, soapui

hope you can able to help on my problem. As of now, I can only test transmissions via SOAP UI in single requests, and the thing is I have a lot of data to transmit and it would be too problematic and laborous to do tests one by one.

Is there a way in SOAP UI wherein I can perform multiple requests at once?Appreciate your feedback and input as always. Thanks!

Comment: Did you even try looking at the documentation? http://www.soapui.org/getting-started/your-first-soapui-project.html

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using Ready API! SoapUI NG Pro and use the a [DataSource](http://readyapi.smartbear.com/structure/steps/data/source/start) test step with a DataSource Loop. The Data Driven Sample Project (available on the starter page of Ready! API) contains a minimal working sample to get you up and running.

Disclaimer: I'm working for the company developing SoapUI and might be biased on the greatness of the Pro version.